Annotation @Valid doesn't work with @RequestPart
I wrote a simple REST service using Spring boot 3.
My controller:
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResourceIdDto upload(@RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile multipartFile, Errors errors) {
    checkErrors(errors);
    byte[] bytes;
    try {
        bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return resourceService.upload(bytes);
}

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        Class<?> aClass = Objects.requireNonNull(binder.getTarget()).getClass();
        boolean isResIdDto = aClass.equals(ResourceIdDto.class);
        if (isResIdDto) {
            binder.addValidators(new ResourceIdValidator());
        } else
            binder.addValidators(new Mp3FileValidator());
    }

private void checkErrors(Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException(errors);
    }
}

My validator:
public class Mp3FileValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MultipartFile.class.equals(clazz);
    }
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        MultipartFile multipartFile = (MultipartFile) target;
        if (multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
            errors.rejectValue("file", "Sent file is empty");
            return;
        }
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        try {
            String detectedType = tika.detect(multipartFile.getInputStream());
            boolean isMp3 = "audio/mpeg".equals(detectedType);
            if (!isMp3) {
                errors.rejectValue("format", "This isn't mp3 file");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

I get an error:
An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public home.nkt.resourceservice.service.dto.ResourceIdDto home.nkt.resourceservice.web.ResourceRestController.upload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.Errors)
For some reason, this approach does not work with @RequestPart, although a similar controller with a request body (@RequestBody) in the form of JSON works correctly.
